# How to dynamically insert an Adobe Edge Preview 4 symbol into a web page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

About Adobe Edge Preview 4 [Click Here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/)

I tried the code below for testing. Expected result is clicking the button, then load the animation dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="edge_includes/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $('body').load('ajax.txt');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Content in **ajax.txt**:

```
<div id="stage" class="EDGE-49494571"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ys-slider_edgePreload.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any solution to load it properly?

Comment: No perfect solution yet. I wrote a small library to handling the complex animation which means no visual editing during debug. I am thinking to use python to import the coordinate, opacity and other properties created by Edge to my lib. If any one can give me the source code of Edge's js lib, this problem may be much easier.

Comment: why don't you do a show/hide?